# Sidebar gets moved below content after adding <?php the_content(); ?>

Tags: html, wordpress, layout, sidebar

I'm currently working on a site and I'm also new to coding WordPress, so I decided to follow some tutorials. After placing  in the code, the sidebar gets moved below the content and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong as everything was fine before I had added that snippet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

http://samplr.paulvictor.nl/demo/

EDIT #2

I can't post the code, I don't know how to use those backticks.

EDIT #3

Here's the screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/4GwhE.jpg

Comment: You don't have to use backticks for posting code. Just indent every line of code with four spaces.

Answer (score 0):

It's because your sidebar is currently printed inside the div with a class of blog_post. Move it outside of that should fix your problem

Hope this helps :)

Comment: It's not inside the blog_post div, it's placed below the content div. I can't post the code as I don't know how to use those backticks.

Comment: studioromeo is correct. Look at your page and do a ViewSource to see the rendered HTML (not the PHP, CSS can't see PHP). Sidebar is inside blog_post. (we don't mean visually, we mean HTML-wise!)

Comment: Then what exactly is causing it to be placed inside the blog_post? If I can't 'see' what needs to be changed, then how can I know what to do?

Comment: The only other reason then is due to invalid markup. Looking at your screenshot I'm seeing a div with display:block set on it without a closing div.

Comment: You're right. I forgot to add a closing div to the clearfix which I have now placed after the pagination. However, this has not fixed the problem unfortunately. The clearfix was originally placed there because the layout was broken (sidebar got placed below the content as well) but was fixed with a clearfix. As I have limited programming knowledge, I don't know what to do next.

Comment: Sorry I can't really help you beyond what I have answered. It's either placed in the wrong location or you're missing a closing tag somewhere.

Comment: Robert: what about posting your PHP (from blog_post to end of sidebar div) on pastebin or similar? You can post a link to that. Once people see code they can tell you how to get sidebar as a sibling to blog_post rather than a child. After that it would be all CSS.

Comment: @Stommepoes; here you go, http://pastebin.com/cycuS3WE I still haven't figured out what the issue is.

Comment: You open a whole bunch of blog_post divs, and  never close them. Then when you have closing divs that you THINK are for content and container, they're not. They're used to close the open blog_post divs.  Your html is horribly messed up, and songdogtech mentions more below. I think fixing your HTML problems will fix everything, won't have to change CSS at all.

Comment: What do you mean with "a whole bunch of blog_post div's"? I only see one blog_post div which is closed or am I looking at something different? Please have a look at the attached screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/fKrcO.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Fix some code errors, like the `ul` tags around `<div class="menu">`and a missing closing `</div>`. Out of place and missing div tags are the leading cause of sidebar problems in Wordpress.

See [[Invalid] Markup Validation of  samplr.paulvictor.nl demo  - W3C Markup Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A//samplr.paulvictor.nl/demo/&doctype=Inline&ss=1&group=0&user-agent=W3C_Validator/1.654). Scroll down in the validation report to see line numbers and source code.

Comment: Thank you @Songdogtech. I've fixed a few issues such as the <ul> problem you've noticed and also the closing div of the content came after the </div> of the main container. So I've fixed that as well. However, I have taken a closer look at the code but I can't figure out why the sidebar is getting "pulled" into the content section. As far as I can see as a beginner programmer, all of those div's have been closed. So I have fixed 2 out of 7 validation errors, I've Googled the whitespace issue but can't seem to find an answer. Updated code here: http://pastebin.com/n8kEQJpf

Comment: Two `divs` are still unclosed. Edit the code on your live site and use the W3C Validator again.

Comment: But the main issue is that I can't find those unclosed div's, I have also checked the remaining WordPress files. Please have a look at this screenshot and tell me what you think: http://i.imgur.com/fKrcO.jpg

Comment: Look in footer.php and sidebar.php

Comment: I have looked and I still can't find what the issue is. This is highly frustrating, I have been looking at this damned code for hours! Thank you for guiding me though, if it's any help, here are the remaining screenshots - footer: http://i.imgur.com/atfmd.jpg sidebar: http://i.imgur.com/iSxo8.jpg